# Error Code: 1093 You can't specify target table 'd' for update in FROM clause

Tags: mysql

Estou tentando deletar o registro da tabela porém me retorna esta mensagem de erro, o que eu to fazendo de errado ? testei de varias formas e sempre caio nessa mensagem

Error Code: 1093 You can't specify target table 'd' for update in FROM clause

```
   DELETE d  FROM tbl_atividades AS d  WHERE codigo NOT IN (
      SELECT 
      a.codigo 
      FROM tbl_atividades AS a
        INNER JOIN tbl_atividades_por_dep AS b 
          ON a.tipo_atividade = b.atividade 
          AND a.departamento = b.departamento
          AND a.tributacao = b.tributacao
    ) AND d.status <> 'CONCLUIDO'
    AND d.extra_urgente_comum <> 'E'
```